# Google permission restriction for SMS and CALL_LOG

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions

My app during testing has RECEIVE_SMS permission. A month ago I receive warning from Google for restrictions about receiving SMS since 9 January 2019. After warning I removed this permission from manifest, but warning is still displayed. 
Now my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Also I changed minSdkVersion to

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 17
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Your `targetSdkVersion` is `26` which leads to run time permissions.

Comment: check your merged manifest. maybe some library is using RECEIVE_SMS permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think google developer console cached my last application state and gave me error. After 2 days error has disapeared.